# php array arrangements

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Hi i convert an collections of string comma separated 0 1 5, 2 3 15, 4 18 20 into an array using this functions as follow:

```
$openHrs = explode(",", $openHrs['open_hours']);
```

The end result are as follow:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 1 5 [1] => 2 3 15 [2] => 4 18 20 )
```

In this array `0 1 5` means `Mon 1 am 5 am` and `4 18 20` means `Thur 6 pm 8 pm`, so first digit represent weekday rest 2 digits represent hours in 24hrs format, now how can i output the existing array into this format?

```
Array ( [0] => Mon 1 am 5 am [1] => Tue 3 am 3 pm [2] => Thur 6 pm 8 pm )
```

Thanks

Comment: not much, i am not sure whether need to break array into sub array and assign each result into weeday and time.

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 2):

I would use array_map to get a filtered version.  You can create dates using mktime() and format them using date().  I believe this should be the solution:

```
$filtered = array_map(function($incoming) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $incoming);
return
    date('D', mktime(0,0,0,1, $parts[0])) . ' ' .
    date('g a', mktime($parts[1])) . ' ' .
    date('g a', mktime($parts[2]));
}, $openHrs);
```

Comment: I tested it with your data you posted and it worked.  :(  Can you specify the output that you're getting that leads you to believe its not working correctly?  Perhaps I can fix it.

Comment: what does $incoming represent? $openHrs result is as follow Array ( [0] => 0 1 5 [1] => 2 3 15 [2] => 4 18 20 ). Should i replace $incoming with $openHrs?

Comment: Oops - I'll edit my code - the variable $array should be $openHrs - that's the incoming variable.  So basically the function converts $incoming from $openHrs - and then does the magic.  In my last example, I had created a temporary variable called $array by accident - instead of copying your code :)

Answer (score 0):

For the **weekday**, I suggest:

```
$weekday=array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');    

foreach ($openHours As &$openHour) {
    $foo = explode(' ',$openHour);
    $openHour=$weekday[$foo].' '. // <-- write yourself a nice function to convert 24h to 12h, maybe there's something like this in PHP already?       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// This will be used for the week days
$weekdays = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');

// Loop through each date
foreach($openHrs as &$temp) {
    // Separate the numbers
    $temp = explode(" ", $temp);

    // Change from a 24 hrs clock to a 12 hrs clock
    $temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? $temp[1] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[1] . 'am';
    $temp[2] = $temp[2] > 12 ? $temp[2] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[2] . 'am';

    // Update the element
    $temp = $weekdays[$temp[0]] . ' ' . $temp[1] . ' ' . $temp[2];
}
```

Comment: @zlippr Oops... I've missed the `&` symbol. Fixed it, try it now

Comment: nope..return nothing $openHrs result is as follow Array ( [0] => 0 1 5 [1] => 2 3 15 [2] => 4 18 20 ) when use foreach it returns nothing..

Comment: @zlippr it works fine for me, have you changed anything in your own code?

Answer (score 0):

I would explode each Arrayelement again with a whitespace as Delimiter so you have a better array structure:

```
Array ( [0] => Array(0, 1, 5), [1] => Array(1, 3, 3) [2] => Array(4, 18, 18) )
```

If you have this structure there are probably several approaches. There might be a solution with date() and timestamps but Iam honestly not to sure about that. An other solution would be. Define another array with the Weekdays.

```
$weekdays = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");
```

Then you can use the numbers that you have as index for that array to output the correct weekday.
The hours can you output with a little selfmade function ala:

```
function twentyFourHourToAmPM($number) {
    if ($number > 12) {
         return ($number - 12)." pm";
    } else {
         return $number." am";
    }
 }
```

Output everything should then work like this:

```
foreach ($openHrs as $key => $value) {
    echo $weekdays[$value[0]]." ".twentyFourHourToAmPM($value[1])." - ".twentyFourHourToAmPM($value[2]);
}
```